# What is happening in the Black Mirror episode "White Bear" (S02E02)?

Tags: plot-explanation, black-mirror

What is happening in the ***Black Mirror*** episode **"White Bear"** (S02E02)?

To me it appeared as if some kind of reality show was going on, wherein a lady was forced to play the part of a murderer.

Is my understanding correct? Can you please explain the complete story more clearly?

Also, the foundation that is running the show is called the "White Bear Justice Park". I couldn't relate to this as well. Why the word 'justice' in the name? Was the lady actually a murderer? Or was she just posed as one to run the show successfully, and maybe make money in the process?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

She has actually assisted her fiancé in the killing of a girl and the show was her punishment (therefore the name justice); From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Bear_(Black_Mirror)):

> After taking her to a nearby forest, Iain tortured and killed Jemima while Victoria recorded his actions on her mobile phone [...]
>
> Having tearfully pleaded guilty and insisting she was 'under Iain's spell', Victoria was given a sentence the judge described as 'proportionate and considered' – to undergo this mob-recorded, poetic justice every day. [...]
>
> Victoria, who still has no clear memory of these events, is driven back to the compound [...] and returned to the room where she woke up. She is placed back in the bedroom chair by Baxter. As she watches footage of Jemima, Baxter places electrodes on her head, wiping Victoria's memory of the day's events [...] ready for Victoria to relive the same events the next day.

Comment: One of the darkest and most haunting episodes of television I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

My explanation is that, she, the lady who's awake and didn't knew where she was. She helped her fiance kill a little girl or she didn't even tried to stop him from doing it or not even tried to help the girl. She instead filmed it while he's torturing and killing her. They got caught and the court found them guilty. But the man killed himself by hanging in prison. Now, the people didn't think that it was fare or justice, as he died soon, without any pain. So they don't want her to do just the same like her fiance. So all the people decided to do it the same way, they did to that little girl. **They made her experience the anguish that little girl had experienced.**